# Netty WebSockets & tcp sockets

Tags: sockets, tcp, websocket, netty

I'm trying mixing TCP and WebSockets in Netty.
I'm have two servers, one with Websockets and one with TCP. All users collected in DefaultUserGroup and cause of this i don't know which user in userGroup come from WebSockets or TCP i can't correctly write to them (DefaultUserGroup.write).

Websocket Server:

```
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(65536));
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
    pipeline.addLast("handler", new WebSocketServerHandler(readQueueHandler));
```

TCP Server:

```
         pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
         pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
         pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
         pipeline.addLast("handler", new MyBusinessLogicHandler(readQueueHandler));
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If `DefaultUserGroup` is a `ChannelGroup`, why not just make two different ChannelGroups, one for TCP and one for WS, and write to both using their respective frames.

Alternately, you could create a POJO with some flags on it that identify the channel type, then when a new connection is established, instantiate a new POJO, set the channel type flag, and stick it on the channel's attachement (`channel.setAttachement(...)`). Then you can check the channel type before writing to it to make sure you format the frame properly (`channel.getAttachement()`).